# gigabit lan setup NOT gettig optimal speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I have a LAN router from vendor which has 4 ports

- all ports are connected to machines
- static ip is mapped to 1 of the machines
- but static machine is routing traffic to other machines via the same router causing network congestion.

How to avoid network congestion ?

Comment: how have you determined that your issue is congestion? its not uncommon for some systems to have difficulty writing data at gigabit speeds (~100MB/s), especially when writing to a mechanical disk or one connected via a slow bus like USB2.

Answer (score 0):

You ensure all theachines are on the same LAN (segment), have the same netmask and the IPs are on the same range.

You have not advised howbyou have set this machine up, but it sounds like one of the above criteria has not been met. I do wonder if you have dome something quirky like have the router assign an external IP address to the 1 system. If that's the case, please advise your config details note clearly and/or change the IP address to be lin the same range as the other IPs and use port mapping/DMZ settings to make the router translate from the internal to external IP.  (Am alternative would be to statically set the IP address and set a secondary intrr face in the same range as the rest of the LAN.)